# JSON language injection in Android Studio?

Tags: json, intellij-idea, autocomplete, android-studio, syntax-highlighting

Android Studio doesn´t support the JSON syntax, but it is possible with language injections in Intellij Idea.

How do I make JSON injectable within Android Studio as it works in Intellij?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2, and this worked for me:

New String and set it to empty string

```
String fakeJson = ""
```

Place cursor in between double quotes
Press Alt-Enter
Select Inject Language -> JSON Files
Press Alt-Enter again to insert annotation

```
//language=JSON
String fakeJson = ""
```

Press Alt-Enter again
Select Edit JSON Fragment
Type your JSON

The important missing step for me was pressing Alt-Enter three times.  Most instructions I found said just press it once and all the magic will happen.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and JSON support is part of the feature set of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, which is a commercial product. There is no way to make its features available in Android Studio.

Comment: But it's still possible to load external inspection modules somehow

Comment: You can install plugins into Android Studio, yes. However, the plugins that comprise the functionality of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate cannot be installed into Android Studio.

Comment: @yole Is this the case even if I actually have a Intellij IDEA Ultimate license available?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate already includes the Android development features from Android Studio